# React Native - BackHandler is not working when keyboard is in opening state

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, keyboard

I need to close a view using setState while closing the keyboard. Using the onBlur event in TextInput, it is working fine. But In android on pressing the hardware back button also keyboard is closing. But onBlur event has not been called. TextInput still focused, but the keyboard closed. 
For backhander, I am using the following code,

```js
componentWillMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
}

handleBackPress = () => {
    console.log("HANDLE BACK PRESSS")
    return true;
}
```

Also I tried the following - Keyboard.addListener

```js
componentWillMount () {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow);
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide);
}
```

```js
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
}

_keyboardDidShow() {
    alert('Keyboard Shown');
  }

_keyboardDidHide = () => {
    alert('Keyboard Hidden');
}
```

But no use. These things are not triggering when the keyboard is in an open state. After the keyboard closed, everything is working as expected.

Suggest some way to get the trigger when pressing the back button while keyboard is in open state.

Comment: Did you found the way out?

Comment: Did you found the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

> import { Keyboard } from 'react-native'

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', 
   this.keyboardDidHide);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
}
keyboardDidHide = () => {
     Keyboard.dismiss();
};
```

Comment: Yes, we are using the keyboard component. While pressing the hardware back button in android, we are not getting the trigger inside the keyboardDidHide method. That's the actual problem.

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.backHandler.remove()
  }

  handleBackPress = () => {
    this.goBack(); // works best when the goBack is async
    return true;
  }

Comment: Please check the question again. I am using the same methods. But the problem is, when the keyboard opened, this backhander not getting any triggers. If the keyboard closed, it is working fine.